# .srt files are hidden in Mac

Tags: macos, mac, video

When I download a video and .srt file for that video the .srt file become invisible but when I play that video and turn on subtitle the subtitle works fine. but I want to be able to see the actual .srt file so I can edit it or upload it to cloud

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in mechanism in macOS to do this, so either an app is doing it, or the file is not actually separate but embedded in the movie file.

Simple test.

- open the folder containing the movie & suspected .srt file on your desktop.
- If you are on High Sierra or Mojave, simply press  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>    <kbd>.</kbd>  [period, full stop] which will show any hidden files. Same again to switch it off.

if not,

- Launch Terminal [Applications/Utilities or use Spotlight]
- Type `cd`follwed by a space, then drag the folder icon from the top of your opened window into terminal - that will auto-fill the correct path for you.
  Hit Enter to complete the directory change.
- Type `ls -l` & hit Enter
- That will show the entire contents of the folder, hidden or not.

If you find the file by either of those methods & you want to permanently unhide it, then you need to do that in Terminal

- Type `chflags nohidden` then a space, then the full path - again you can do that by dragging the file into Terminal, or if you are still using the same Terminal session as above by simply typing the file's full name.
  Hit Enter.